# Swift 5.1 Initialilize Array Multidimensional with unsafeUninitializedCapacity

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, initialization

In order to initialize a two-dimension Int array following 
https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0245-array-uninitialized-initializer.md

```
var myArray = Array<Int>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 10) { buffer, initializedCount in
    for x in 1..<5 {
        buffer[x] = x
    }
    buffer[0] = 10
    initializedCount = 5
}
// myArray == [10, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I've tried next two code, but they doesn'work:

```
var myArray = [[Int]](unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 3) { bufferfilas, initializedCountfilas in
    for x in 0..<3 {
        bufferfilas[x] = [Int](unsafeUninitializedCapacity:3) {buffercolumnas, initializedCountcolumnas in
            for y in 0..<3{
                buffercolumnas[y] = y 
            }
            initializedCountcolumnas = 3
        }
    }
    initializedCountfilas = 9
}
```

And the second:

```
var myArray = [[Int]](var myArray = [[Int]](unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 9) { buffer, initializedCount in
for x in 0..<3 {
    for y in 0..<3{
        buffer[x][y] = (x*10)+y 
    }
}
    initializedCount = 9
}
```

Which one is the correct way to initialize a two-dimension array in swift 5.1?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just want to initialise a 2 dimensional array or you need access to uninitialise storage as well ?

Comment: Both of them, the main target is initialization, but I would like understand unsafeUninitializedCapacity in Swift5.1. In previous versions of Swift works: `self.cells = [[Cell]](unsafeUninitializedCapacity:filas, initializingWith:[Cell](unsafeUninitializedCapacity:columnas, initializingWith:  UnsafeMutableBufferPointer, Cell(row: 0,col: 0)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the initialiser declaration from [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3200717-init)

```
init(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: Int, initializingWith initializer: (inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Element>, inout Int) throws -> Void) rethrows
```

To create a 2D dimensional array the `Element` should be another array.
Following is the example if you want your second array to be initialise as normal array instead of using the `unsafeUninitializedCapacity`

```
var my2DArray = Array<Array<Int>>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 10) { (buffer: inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Array<Int>>, count: inout Int) in
    for a in 0..<5 {
        buffer[a] = [a]
    }
    count = 5
}
```

For the unsafe version

```
var my2DArrayUnsafe = Array<Array<Int>>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 10) { (buffer: inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Array<Int>>, count: inout Int) in
    for a in 0..<5 {
        buffer[a] = Array<Int>(unsafeUninitializedCapacity: 10, initializingWith: { (subBuffer: inout UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int>, subCount: inout Int) in
            for subA in 0..<5 {
                subBuffer[subA] = subA
            }
            subCount = 5
        })
    }
    count = 5
}
```

Comment: Great! It Works! Thanks a lot!